# autocompleter does not submit form values

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm working with struts 2 and jquery plugin.

I have a jsp where I have defined two elements, a select and an autocompleter.
I need to filter the products selected from the provider previously selected:

```
 <s:form id='myForm'>
 <s:select list="providers" value="provider.id" listKey="id" name="provider.id"/>
 <sj:autocompleter 
 id="productId" 
 name="productDescription" 
 value="%{productDescription}" 
 listenTopics="providerChanged"
 href="%{url_products}"
 formIds="myForm" 
 />
```

The problem is that the autocompleter does not submit the latest selected values in the sj:select while typing in it. So when url_products is called, an old value for the provider.id is sent to the action.

Plese note that I added formIds in the autocompleter but does not resolve the problem.

Any ideas???

Comment: Add you jquery code. Is it automatically generated our have you written it?

Comment: It's autogenerated. That is all the code I have in my jsp for having the autocompleter working. So the autocompleter correctly shows the products and starts filtering them while typing on it BUT I want to filter those products by the provider selected and the latest provider.id is not rendered to the action when url_products is processed.

Comment: Can you find the JS and paste it, perhaps people could help more if they can see the actual code js code.

Comment: @clanmilano I'm having exactly a same problem here. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not add any code at JS, so I include some other code related that can describe better what I've implemented:

Code in the action:

```
public List<Provider> getProviders() {
    return this.providerService.getAllProviders();
}

public String[] getAllProducts() {
            //provider.id has an old value when this methood is called
    List<String> productsDescriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (term != null && term.length() > 0)
    {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products = this.productService.getAllProducts();
            for (Product product : products) {
                String descriptionProduct =     product.getDescription();
                if    (StringUtils.contains(descriptionProduct.toLowerCase(), term.toLowerCase()))
                {
                        productsDescriptions.add(descriptionProduct);
                }
            }
    }
    return productsDescriptions.toArray(new String[productsDescriptions.size()]);
}

public String getProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    return this.productDescription;
}

public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}

public String showProducts() {
    return "showProducts";
}
```

URL at jsp:

```
<s:url id="url_products" action="purchaseNavegation" method="showProducts"/>
```

struts.xml:

```
<action name="purchaseNavigation" class="purchaseNavigationAction">
        <result name="showProducts" type="json">
            <param name="root">allProducts</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with sj:autocompleter lately and had a very similar problem. I wasn't sure if it was my messing around on the back end doing that - I wanted to autocompleter to match on the last item being typed:

This and that and someth..

I still wanted to match on 'something' but without overwriting 'This and that and ' if 'something' was selected - anyway, to get to the point, it wasn't my splicing and dicing that caused the error it was a simple fix of adding:

```
forceValidOption="false"
```

to the sj:autocompleter.  By default, this value is true if you omit it.

Try it and see if it works for you